# Drag and Drop .gif into <div> box

Tags: html, css

Most of my code is from the website: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp.

I've added the snippets of my .css and .html code. I'd like to be able to drag either of the two .gif images into the "first"  box, though I'm not able to do this (in CoffeeCup Free HTML Editor). Perhaps I'm not using IDs correctly?

```css
div.content {
     height:70px;
     width:350px;
     border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
     float:left;
     margin:5px;
     }
     


     div#first:{
      }
      
      div#second:{
       }
       
       div#third{
        }
        
        div#fourth{ 
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="content" id="first">Block 1</div>
<div class="content" id="second">Block 2</div>
<div class="content" id="third">Block 3</div>
<div class="content" id = "fourth">Block 4</div>

<div id="first" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>

<img id="drag1" src="squig.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
<img id="drag2" src="squig2.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two Solutions for you, choose which you need.
1. You need this in your HTML-Code:

```
<div class="content" id="first" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Block 1</div>
<div class="content" id="second">Block 2</div>
<div class="content" id="third">Block 3</div>
<div class="content" id = "fourth">Block 4</div>
```

You have to delete this line:

```
<div id="first" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

2.Another Solution without changing nothing in your HTML-Code.

Add this in your CSS-Code:

```
#first {
     height:70px;
     width:350px;
     border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
     float:left;
     margin:5px;
}
```